# Wind force field blender

Tags: cloth-simulation, force-fields

The wind force effect on my flags is not played farther than 250 frames
can someone please help? thanks

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie: i first wanted to comment, what has rigid body sim to do with cloth...then i looked at the answers...you are right. I was mislead by the title of "rigid simulation" -  so i changed the title to rigid/cloth sim so that people who search for cloth sim will find it better ;)

Answer (score 1):

in cloth settings -> cache -> change simulation end to a higher value and bake your simulation again.

[image]